Widget with horizontal bar
Good afternoon everyone,
I feel like I might be asking a basic question, as this seems like a relatively easy problem, but I've been banging my head against the wall for days and have tested everything I could within the limits of my abilities.
In summary, I am creating an Android APP with Android Studio, and within the APP, there is a horizontal bar that spans from one edge of the screen to the other (with relative margins, but that’s the idea). It works perfectly within the APP.
However, I want the functionality of the APP to be equally translated into a Widget. But in the Widget, I am not managing, in any way, to adjust the dimensions of the horizontal bar to fit the screen or the dimensions of the Widget.
that make sense, the widgetWidth never adjusts to the screen, and something is always left out.
WidgetProvider:
  val widgetWidth = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH)

I have tried a fixed value:
    val widgetWidth = 300 or 600

or even pixels:
           val widgetWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels

or adding a margin:
            val widgetWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels - (2 * widgetMargin)

And in the widget layout.xml, I have something like this:
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Beginning" />

 
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="End" />
</LinearLayout>

I also tried setting a fixed value for the bar in the layout, but it also doesn’t work.
One of the details for which I need this exact fit is that I use, in the WidgetProvider, certain percentage values of the bar to place text, such as:
       val marker0Pos = 0f
            val marker25Pos = (widgetWidth * 0.25).toFloat()
            val marker50Pos = (widgetWidth * 0.50).toFloat()
            val marker75Pos = (widgetWidth * 0.75).toFloat()
            val marker100Pos = widgetWidth.toFloat()

But even though the Logs show me percentage values that make sense, the widgetWidth never adjusts to the screen, and something is always left out.
enter image description hereenter image description here
If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it. Because without this step, the entire idea fails.
